# Iterate over files and update rows in directory, preferably using Bash script

Tags: bash, file, for-loop, iteration

I have   300 text files in a directory in following format

```
 regional_vol_WM1.txt

    651328 651328
    553949 553949
    307287 307287
    2558 2558       



regional_vol_WM2.txt

    651328 651328
    553949 553949
    307287 307287
    2138 2138
```

I would like to iterate over all these txt files and perform calculation on 4th row both columns using the formula

```
(Value of fourth row /0.824198)*0.8490061
```

and a new file with a new name regional_vol_WM2_prop.txt should be created,with first three rows having same value and fourth row with updated value with newly calculated output

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Isn't this a *SuperUser* kind of question?

Comment: 4th row is having two columns, which value you are interested in ?

Comment: @PS. Both values should be updated

Comment: @redneb, I am able iterate through the files in the directory i have written the code for it, i just want a means to create a new file with newly updated data in fourth row

Comment: Do you *really* need to do it in plain bash?

Comment: @JakubM. Not necessarily but bash would be useful

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
FNR == 1 {
  newfilename = FILENAME ; sub(".txt", "_prop.txt", newfilename)
  printf "" > newfilename
}
FNR == 4 {
  $1=($1/0.824198)*0.8490061
  $2=($2/0.824198)*0.8490061
}
{
  print >> newfilename
}
' regional_vol_WM*[0-9].txt
```

Comment: I am getting an error when i run the awk file in my directory :  following is the error  awk: 15: unexpected character '.'

Comment: You sure you have the terminating single quote?  awk thinks that the filename arg is part of the awk script, which it shouldn't.  It's a filename glob in bash.

Comment: @DannyDaglas   No i do no have a terminating single quote, A normal file name goes by following naming convention : regional_vol_GM_122.txt

Comment: In short, the script file should be of the form: #!/bin/bash \n awk script filenames.  Everything after the "awk" and before the filename pattern should be enclosed in single quotes (the script).  The filename pattern should match what you require to be processed.  Also, make sure that there are no single-quotes in the awk script portion.

Comment: I am still getting an error  regional_vol_WM_atlas[0-151].txt: No such file or directory

Comment: @DevanDevak: File globs don't work like that in bash.  It doesn't understand whole number ranges.  To get something like that to work, replace `X[0-151].txt` with `X[0-9].txt X[0-9][0-9].txt X1[0-4][0-9].txt X15[01].txt`.  (Replace `X` with `regional_vol_WM_atlas`.  I didn't want to type all that out repeatedly.)  Please note that some of these patterns may not match and you'll get something like 'xyz: No such file or directory'.  This is ok.  You will have to verify for yourself that your files were processed regardless of the error messages you get.

Comment: I have made those changes and my files were not processed at all